# What is wrong with my @typescript-eslint/member-ordering configuration?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

My lint commands are immediately failing with the following error:

```
Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering" is invalid:
                Value ["signature","public-static-field","protected-static-field","private-static-field","public-decorated-field","protected-decorated-field","private-decorated-field","public-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-instance-field","public-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-abstract-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method"] should be string.
                Value ["signature","public-static-field","protected-static-field","private-static-field","public-decorated-field","protected-decorated-field","private-decorated-field","public-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-instance-field","public-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-abstract-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method"] should be equal to one of the allowed values.
                Value "private-abstract-field" should be equal to one of the allowed values.
                Value "private-abstract-field" should be array.
                Value "private-abstract-field" should match exactly one schema in oneOf.
                Value ["signature","public-static-field","protected-static-field","private-static-field","public-decorated-field","protected-decorated-field","private-decorated-field","public-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-instance-field","public-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-abstract-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method"] should be object.
                Value ["signature","public-static-field","protected-static-field","private-static-field","public-decorated-field","protected-decorated-field","private-decorated-field","public-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-instance-field","public-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-abstract-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method"] should match exactly one schema in oneOf.
```

But my configuration matches the [documentation](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/member-ordering/) for this rule.

My configuration:

```json
"@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": [
    "error",
    {
        "default": [
            "signature",
            "public-static-field",
            "protected-static-field",
            "private-static-field",
            "public-decorated-field",
            "protected-decorated-field",
            "private-decorated-field",
            "public-instance-field",
            "protected-instance-field",
            "private-instance-field",
            "public-abstract-field",
            "protected-abstract-field",
            "private-abstract-field",
            "public-constructor",
            "protected-constructor",
            "private-constructor",
            "public-static-method",
            "protected-static-method",
            "private-static-method",
            "public-decorated-method",
            "protected-decorated-method",
            "private-decorated-method",
            "public-instance-method",
            "protected-instance-method",
            "private-instance-method",
            "public-abstract-method",
            "protected-abstract-method",
            "private-abstract-method"
        ]
    }
],
```

I've updated to the latest version of all of my lint plugins and definitions and still no joy. Any ideas appreciated.

```json
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.51.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.51.0",
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the exact same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"private-abstract-field" and "private-abstract-method" are no longer accepted values.

Please see the [official documentation](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/member-ordering/#default-configuration) for the current list of accepted values.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same error recently, while updateing angular 14 -> 15.

I found no real reason for this, but removing all instances of member-ordering-... solved the issue for me.